# Error in running an implementation of list

Tags: c++, runtime-error

This is the part of the code where I'm facing the problem:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ID{
    int value;
    ID *nxtElement;
};

struct SqLand{
    ID *id;
    SqLand *next;
};

int main(){

    for(int p, i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        SqLand *nptr = new SqLand;

        cin >> p;
        ID *buff = new ID;
        buff = nptr->id;
        for(int j = 0; j < p; j++){
            cin >> buff->value;
            //cout << "Garbage";
            buff = buff->nxtElement;
        }
        buff = NULL;
        //cout << "WILL";
        delete nptr;
        delete buff;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that on running this program and inserting the value of p more than 1, the program exits after 2 more inputs.
For example, starting like this:

```
2
1
3
```

This is where the program exits

If both the cout statements are un-commented here are the outputs:

```
2
1
Garbage3
GarbageWILL
```

And another:

```
3
1
Garbage2
Garbage
```

All the programs exit after their respective last lines. What is the error in my program? It's a part of another program so that don't expect this snippet to make any sense. I only want to know where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your program crashes because you attempt to dereference a null pointer. What do you suppose the value of `nptr->id` is?

Comment: also where is `i` defined? this code wont compile, it looks like you edit `p` in your for loop

Comment: Also you are not successfully deleting all of your memory when you just call `delete buff`

Comment: You should urgently learn how to use the debugger to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: `nptr->id` -- `buff = buff->nxtElement;`  You're accessing pointers that are not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

What i can understand from your code this ... (with fix)

```
struct ID {
    ID(int val = -1, ID* _nxtElement = NULL) :
            value(val), nxtElement(_nxtElement) {
    }
    int value;
    ID *nxtElement;
};

struct SqLand {
    SqLand(ID* _id = NULL, SqLand* _next = NULL) :
            id(_id), next(_next) {
    }
    ID *id;
    SqLand *next;
};

const int size = 3;
int main() {

    SqLand* head = new SqLand;
    SqLand* tmp = head;
    for (int p, i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        cin >> p;
        tmp->id = new ID;
        ID* tmpID = tmp->id;
        for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
            cin >> tmpID->value;

            // avoid unnecessary allocate
            if (j < p - 1) {
                tmpID->nxtElement = new ID;
                tmpID = tmpID->nxtElement;
            }
        }

        // avoid unnecessary allocate
        if(i < size - 1) {
            tmp->next = new SqLand;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in your code you miss allocate for `nptr->id` and you miss the most important the `head` of `list` (`SqLand *nptr = new SqLand;`).